# Nested parcelable runtime execption

Tags: java, android, parcelable, runtimeexception

I am working on an Android app where I create an `ArrayList` of `Parcelable` object that contains an `ArrayList` of `Parcelable` object. To fit my case, it's a `public ArrayList<FolderModel> folderList_;`

My goal is to pass this `ArrayList` through an `Intent`, hence the `Parcelable` implementation, my problem arise when I try to get the data out of the `Intent` where I get this error code:

```
Parcel android.os.Parcel@9aa641d: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881389 at offset 1696.
```

I can't really make sense out of it. I looked around but couldn't find anything related to my issue.

Another funny behavior is that, if I comment out the `folderName_` inside my `ExerciseModel` in `public void writeToParcel` then it works. Can anyone help me figure out this mystery?

As far as I could see, the two classes are implemented properly as `Parcelable` object, I will continue to look for an answer, but I feel like I have reached a wall.

After further testing, I can safely transmit an `ArrayList` of `ExerciseModel` which would point me in the direction that the problem happens either in `FolderModel` or in the `ArrayList` in this class.

All the code can be browsed at https://github.com/louckas/TrainingPlan, I will only share the relevant class below.

FolderModel class:

```
public class FolderModel implements Parcelable {
    String folderName_ = "Folder";
    Boolean extended_ = false;
    ArrayList<ExerciseModel> exerciseList_;

    public FolderModel(String folderName, Boolean extended, ArrayList<ExerciseModel> exerciseList) {
        folderName_ = folderName;
        extended_ = extended;
        exerciseList_ = exerciseList;
    }

    protected FolderModel(Parcel in) {
        folderName_ = in.readString();
        byte tmpExtended_ = in.readByte();
        extended_ = tmpExtended_ == 0 ? null : tmpExtended_ == 1;
        exerciseList_ = in.createTypedArrayList(ExerciseModel.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Creator<FolderModel> CREATOR = new Creator<FolderModel>() {
        @Override
        public FolderModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new FolderModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public FolderModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new FolderModel[size];
        }
    };

    public String getFolderName_() {
        return folderName_;
    }

    public Boolean getExtended_() {
        return extended_;
    }

    public void setExtended_(boolean extended) { extended_ = extended; }

    public List<ExerciseModel> getExerciseList_() { return exerciseList_; }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(folderName_);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            parcel.writeParcelableList(exerciseList_, i);
        }
    }
}
```

ExerciseModel class:

```
public class ExerciseModel  implements Parcelable {
    String exerciseName_;
    String description_;
    String folderName_;

    public ExerciseModel(String exerciseName, String description, String folderName) {
        exerciseName_ = exerciseName;
        description_ = description;
        folderName_ = folderName;
    }

    protected ExerciseModel(Parcel in) {
        exerciseName_ = in.readString();
        description_ = in.readString();
        folderName_ = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<ExerciseModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ExerciseModel>() {
        @Override
        public ExerciseModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ExerciseModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ExerciseModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ExerciseModel[size];
        }
    };

    public String getExerciseName_() { return exerciseName_; }

    public String getDescription_() { return description_; }

    public String getFolderName_() { return folderName_; }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(exerciseName_);
        parcel.writeString(description_);
        parcel.writeString(folderName_);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking further into it, I figured out the issue !

The problem was in the `FolderModel` in the `writeToParcel` the `extended` field wasn't put into the `Parcelable` which mean 2 arguments and in the `protected FolderModel(Parcel in)` constructor I was reading 3. Therefore, the problem.

Here is the correction I had to do in order to solve my issue:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(folderName_);
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (extended_ ? 1 : 0));
    parcel.writeTypedList(exerciseList_);
}
```